# find the least angle of a line to X axis in C#

Tags: c#, vector, angle

Let's say we define two vectors by subtracting the end points of two lines.

```
V1 = Pa - Pb;
V2 = Pc - Pd;
```

and we define the X axis as the following vector.

```
var V = new System.Windows.Vector(1, 0);
```

How can we know which one of the two two vectors V1 and V2 has the least angle to X axis.

Comment: Actually if you need to know which vector is closer to X axis(and only X), you can use the values of `X` coordinates of these vectors. These `X` coords are the lenghts of projection of both of vectores at OX axis, which one is shorter has the bigger angle, the longer projection means sharper angle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options: You can calculate the angles between `V1` and `V` and `V2` and `V` with the `AngleBetween` Function:

```
var angle1 = Vector.AngleBetween(V1,V);
var angle2 = Vector.AngleBetween(V2,V);

if (angle1 < angle2) {
    //V1 is closer to V
}else{
    //V2 is closer to V
}
```

or you could also normalize your vectors and compare their `y` values afterwards:

```
V1.Normalize();
V2.Normalize();
if(Math.Abs(V1.Y) < Math.Abs(V2.Y)){
    //V1 is closer
}else{
    //V2 is closer
}
```

I would prefer the first method, since the `Normalize()` function actually changes the original Vector so you would need to make a copy if you wanted to use them afterwards. Also you can use the first version in order to compare them to any other vector `V` without needing to adjust the code.

Edit: Actually the first version only chooses the vector with the smallest angle to the `V` vector and **not** to the x-axis. So if you want to compare to the axis instead of just the vector you should do the angle calculation with copies of `V1` and `V2` with absolute `x` and `y` values:

```
var ref1 = new System.Windows.Vector(Math.Abs(V1.X),Math.Abs(V1.Y));
var ref2 = new System.Windows.Vector(Math.Abs(V2.X),Math.Abs(V2.Y));
var angle1 = Vector.AngleBetween(ref1,V);
var angle2 = Vector.AngleBetween(ref2,V);

if (angle1 < angle2) {
    //V1 is closer to V
}else{
    //V2 is closer to V
}
```

Looking at it like this, the normalization method might be the better choice after all. (But be sure to call `Normalize()` on copies)

Comment: Thank you for the extra recommendation about the `Normalize()`.

Comment: You should probably also take a look at my last edit, I fixed some things that only worked partially.

Answer (score 2):

Normalize both and find one with higher absolute value of x.

Alternatively, angle between two vectors `a` and `b` is `arccos((a.x*b.x+a.y*b.y)/(a.Length*b.Length))` (undefined if one of vectors is zero)

Answer (score 1):

Check the following solution. May fulfill your query.Add reference Windowsbase to project. Very Important.

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace Vectors
{

    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Define Points
            Point Pa = new Point(5.0,1.0);
            Point Pb = new Point(10.0,3.0);
            Point Pc = new Point(7.0,10.0);
            Point Pd = new Point(1.0,3.0);
            Vector V1 = Pa - Pb;
            Vector V2 = Pc - Pd;

            Vector V = new Vector(1, 0);

            double Phi1 = Math.Atan2(V1.Y, V1.X)*180/Math.PI;
            double Phi2 = Math.Atan2(V2.Y, V2.X)*180/Math.PI;

            // Check for -ve angle and take 180 degree complement.
            Phi1 = (Phi1 >= 0) ? Phi1 : 180 + Phi1;
            Phi2 = (Phi2 >= 0) ? Phi2 : 180 + Phi2;

            if(Phi1<=Phi2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Vector V1 has a least angle");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Vector V2 has a least angle");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   double compare() {
        Point p0 = new Point(0, 0);
        Point p1 = new Point(100, 100);
        Point p2 = new Point(100, -100);
        Vector v0 = new System.Windows.Vector(1, 0);

        var v1 = p1 - p0;
        var v2 = p2 - p0;

        var value1 = Vector.AngleBetween(v0, v1); //value = 45 
        var value2 = Vector.AngleBetween(v0, v2); //value = -45

        value1 = Math.Abs(value1);
        value2 = Math.Abs(value2);

        /* Or if you want to compare the value of the angle
        if (value1 < 0)
            value1 += 360;

        if (value2 < 0)
            value2 += 360;
        */

        return Math.Min(value1,value2);

    }
```